# Case insensitive bash auto-complete

Tags: linux, bash, case-insensitive, case-sensitive

Is there a way to make the file/dir auto-complete in bash case insensitive?

For example I would like to write:
`/opt/ibm/whatever/test` [TAB]

And bash will auto-complete it to:
`/opt/IBM/Whatever/TESTfile`

Or at least only the last part of `test` to `TESTfile`.

I know that filesystems are case-sensitive, I just don't want to remember which parts are UPPER-case, I want auto-complete to fix the path for me.

And if I have both `TESTfile` and `testfile`, just show me both of them like bash does today with auto-complete conflicts.

Answer (score 4):

To add a little bit to this discussion;

```
shopt -s nocaseglob
```

This will affect wildcard expansion, so ls w* would show w1.txt W1.txt. However, as I understand it, tab-completion will ignore this setting.

You can affect tab-completion with inputrc;

```
echo 'set completion-ignore-case On' >> /etc/inputrc
```

Or (~/.inputrc if your system is setup this way)

Andrew